# Сохранить изображение с формы Jframe в файловую систему

Tags: java, swing, изображения, jframe

```
save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Rectangle rec = label.getBounds();
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(rec.width,rec.height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        paint(img.getGraphics());
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        int result = chooser.showDialog(Form.this,"Save");
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            try
            {
                ImageIO.write(img,"*.jpg", file);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Form.this,"The image was saved!", "",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } catch (IOException ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Form.this,"Error!", "",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Form.this,"Canceled by user");
        }
    }
});
```

Не сохраняет, хотя работает вроде бы верно. Помогите разобраться где я ошибку допустил.

Comment: Oh man, it's russian StackOverflow) you must go to original stackoverflow)

Comment: Или вы можете перевести вопрос на русский язык.

Comment: @KryTer_NexT перевел)

Comment: Слушай, у меня похожая ситуация была, только с текстовым файлом, я никак не мог сохранять файлы на `C:/` диск, поменял его на `D:/` все работало)

Comment: второй параметр `ImageIO.write` (formatName) должен быть просто "jpg"